# Is an open port 10243 on Windows 7 something to worry about?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I recently did a portscan on my Windows 7 installation (Results below) and found something that surprized me. Especially the ports 2869 and 10234 seemed strange.

I used TCPView to check which processes are listening on these ports, to see that they are all used by "System". Is there any way to get more information? Is this potentially dangerous?

[image: TCPView]

Here is the result of the port scan

```
554/tcp   open  rtsp
2869/tcp  open  icslap
10243/tcp open  unknown
```

I disabled Home Network sharing to close several more ports, but 10243 still remains open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the crulpit was the **Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service**, which baffles me a little, since `wmpnetwk.exe` is indeed listed among those things.